# How can I count specific item in sqlite database?

Tags: java, sqlite, count

How can I count specific items in a SQLite database? Here's what I have tried so far:

```
 String Query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE date = '" + 2015 + "'";
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query);
 jtextfield.setText(String.valueOf(rs));
```

Comment: You're looking for any date that occurs within the year 2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your query is correct you need to read the result in a proper way:

```
String Query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE date = '" + 2015 + "'";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query);
int count    = rs.next() ? rs.getInt(1) : 0;
jtextfield.setText(String.valueOf(count));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String query = String.format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE date = '%d'", 2015);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
int count = 0;
try {
    rs.next();
    count = rs.getInt(1);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    count = 0;
}
String rowCount = String.valueOf(count);
jtextfield.setText(rowCount);
```

According to [the java style guide from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html), instance variables should be lowercase and there are a few other stylistic things you'll find you need to change to conform to it. I don't like inner classes or more than one function call in a line, but that's a personal preference, so you'll notice I've changed your code style a little. Feel free to ignore it if you disagree.